# How to add values to a ListView in other activity?

Tags: java, android, listview

In my app I have a [alertdialog](/questions/tagged/alertdialog) which contains a button named "add to favorites", when I click on that button, I want to send values to a [listview](/questions/tagged/listview) in another activity, the values I'm trying to add are retrieved from a [arraylist](/questions/tagged/arraylist), can anyone help?

This is what I have:

```
.setNegativeButton("Favoritos",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which){

        int position=(int)marker.getTag();
        final ListView listReprFav=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listaFavRepresentantes);
            ListAdapter adapterReprFav=new SimpleAdapter(
            (MapsActivity.this),
            listaRepresentantes,
            R.layout.list_item_representantes_fav,
            new String[]{listaOportunidades.get(position).get("Designacao"),listaOportunidades.get(position).get("Morada")},
            new int[]{R.id.DesignacaoReprFav,R.id.Cidade});

        listReprFav.setAdapter(adapterReprFav);
        }
}
```

Comment: use the ArrayList as static and from after putting the value to the the ArrayList just call adapterReprFav.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: Don't use static. Use [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) and post an event passing the new list & inside the adapter handle the event & call notifyDataSetChanged().

Comment: Where are you starting the other activity? It has already started while you are doing this?

Comment: @EmreAlparslan I don't want to start the other activity in here, I just want to send the values to the listview in the other activity

Comment: You need to have 'context' of the other activity in this activity. Then you can write a function that updates ListView. Do you pass 'context' of the other activity?

Comment: @EmreAlparslan no

Answer (score 0):

First create a Global class that will keep Context of ListView activity.

```
public class Global extends Application {
    Context context;
}
```

Then you need to create a public method in the activity that contains ListView:

```
public class ListViewActivity extends Activity {

    public List<String> listItems;
    public ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ....

        Global.context = this; //Set context in Global.

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
        (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, 
        listItems);


        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    //This method will add a new String to listItems array and 
    //notifies adapter for changes.
    public void addItemAndRefreshListView(String[] newItems){
        for(int i = 0; i<newItems.length; i++){
            listItems.add(newItem);
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

After that, in onClick of Dialog button:

```
.setNegativeButton("Favoritos",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which){
        if(Global.context != null){
            ((ListViewActivity) Global.context).addItemAndRefreshListView(values);
        }
    }
}
```